# List all public methods of an instance within Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, code-generation

Sometimes I face the problem of converting an object in another, meaning that I have object `source` of type `Source` from which I have to create object `target` of type `Target`, such as (this is in Java, but any OO language would fit):

```
public class Source {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private float value;
    private int secondValue;

    ...

    // getters, setters and other methods

}

public class Target {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    ...

    // getters, setters and other methods

}
```

Usually, this means setting several members of `target` with values read (or derived) from `source`, e.g.:

```
target.setCode(source.getCode());
target.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(source.getSecondValue() / 100.0));
```

When type `Source` has more than ten methods, this gets frustrating and one can easily miss something.

This is when editing code in the IDE, so no reflection would work straight away (of course it will if called from a plugin or similar).

Is there any command in Eclipse for listing all the public methods available from an instance? Of course this should take into consideration inherited methods too (so copy pasting from type `Source` declaration won't work)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that contains all public methods of `Source`, including inherited methods:

1. Create a new class:

   ```
   public class Temp {
       Source source;
   }
   ```
2. Right-click on `source` and choose ***Source > Generate Delegate Methods...***
3. In the dialog deselect the methods you want to exclude and click *OK*
4. Copy the full list of methods from the *Outline* view.